# How to add .xml extension to all files in a folder in Unix/Linux

Tags: php, python, linux, shell, unix

I want to rename all files in a folder and add a `.xml` extension. I am using Unix.  How can I do that?

Comment: These tags create confusion. Do you want to do this in PHP, Python or Unix shell?

Comment: rename 's/$/\.xml/' * reference: http://askubuntu.com/a/74368

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On the shell, you can do this:

```
for file in *; do
    if [ -f ${file} ]; then
        mv ${file} ${file}.xml
    fi
done
```

**Edit**

To do this recursively on all subdirectories, you should use `find`:

```
for file in $(find -type f); do
    mv ${file} ${file}.xml
done
```

On the other hand, if you're going to do anything more complex than this, you probably shouldn't use `shell` scripts.

**Better still**

Use the comment provided by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) below:

```
find . -type f -exec mv {} {}.xml ';'
```

Comment: how do i do it recursively on all sub directories too

Comment: Use `find` to find the files; `find . -type f -exec mv {} {}.xml ';'`.

Comment: also if they already have a .xml extension i dont want them to be renamed

Comment: Yeah, lets not carried away with changing the question in the comments.  Check out http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html to see how to test if your file name matches a ".xml" at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if this is standard, but my `Perl` package (Debian/Ubuntu) includes a `/usr/bin/prename` (and a symlink just `rename`)  which has no other purpose:

```
rename 's/$/.xml/' *
```

Comment: how do i do it recursively on all sub directories too but not on .xml files. i.e files that are not already renamed

Comment: With `$(find -type f)` instead of `*`. And adapting the regex with an assertion `s/(?<!\.xml)$/.xml/`

Comment: You can use rename with -n flag to test how the renaming would be without actually renaming the files.

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type f \! -name '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/$/.xml/'
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Python**:

Use `os.listdir` to find names of all files in a directory. If you need to *recursively* find all files in sub-directories as well, use `os.walk` instead. Its API is more complex than `os.listdir` but it provides powerful ways to recursively walk directories.

Then use `os.rename` to rename the files.

Comment: @Web Developer: did you just -1 me for providing you an answer? Seriously?